# iOS get UI element from XCUIElement

Tags: ios, testing, xctest

I'm trying to test a custom UITextField element in a UITableView showing error message after a button click. My element has an error icon inside so if I can have my custom UITextField object in test class, I can check if the icon is visible or not. I can get a XCUIElement object by doing:

```
XCUIApplication().tables.cells.containingType(.StaticText, identifier: "My placeholder").childrenMatchingType(.TextField).element
```

How can I get a UITextField object inside of a XCTestCase class?

Answer (score 1):

You can't interact with the actual UITextField through XCTest because the app is running in a separate process to the UI test runner.

You can check if the text field is visible (i.e. It exists in the view hierarchy and it is on the screen) by calling `.hittable` on the element that you have.

If you want to test the internals of your custom object, use a unit test, where you will be able to interact with the actual UITextField, rather than an XCUIElement representing it.